computing the sum of rectangular haar features using the integral image
I wanted to use this guys code to calculate the integral image and sum regions for Haar features because I couldn't find anything else reliable and didn't really want to do it myself. But now it seems that this code doesn't work anyway and I can't get it to work but want to make it work using the padded integral image.
I just don't really understand what to input for the sum_region function. He calculates the integral image using to_integral_image() which is correct, but then the bit I don't understand is the sum_region function which doesn't seem to work for me when I test it, the whole flipping the coordinates and the padding of the integral image has confused me and I can't get my head over it it's really frustrating.
The integral for me was calculated perfectly, but the sum_region() function just doesn't seem to work. I tried adding one to both the bottom_right coordinates but that didn't work for edge cases.
If anyone could help me get over this annoying mental brain-fog I'd really appreciate it.
def to_integral_image(img_arr):
    """
    Calculates the integral image based on this instance's original image data.
    :param img_arr: Image source data
    :type img_arr: numpy.ndarray
    :return Integral image for given image
    :rtype: numpy.ndarray
    """
    # an index of -1 refers to the last row/column
    # since row_sum is calculated starting from (0,0),
    # rowSum(x, -1) == 0 holds for all x
    row_sum = np.zeros(img_arr.shape)
    # we need an additional column and row
    integral_image_arr = np.zeros((img_arr.shape[0] + 1, img_arr.shape[1] + 1))
    for x in range(img_arr.shape[1]):
        for y in range(img_arr.shape[0]):
            row_sum[y, x] = row_sum[y-1, x] + img_arr[y, x]
            integral_image_arr[y+1, x+1] = integral_image_arr[y+1, x-1+1] + row_sum[y, x]
    return integral_image_arr


def sum_region(integral_img_arr, top_left, bottom_right):
    """
    Calculates the sum in the rectangle specified by the given tuples.
    :param integral_img_arr:
    :type integral_img_arr: numpy.ndarray
    :param top_left: (x, y) of the rectangle's top left corner
    :type top_left: (int, int)
    :param bottom_right: (x, y) of the rectangle's bottom right corner
    :type bottom_right: (int, int)
    :return The sum of all pixels in the given rectangle
    :rtype int
    """
    # swap tuples
    top_left = (top_left[1], top_left[0])
    bottom_right = (bottom_right[1], bottom_right[0])
    if top_left == bottom_right:
        return integral_img_arr[top_left]
    top_right = (bottom_right[0], top_left[1])
    bottom_left = (top_left[0], bottom_right[1])
    return integral_img_arr[bottom_right] - integral_img_arr[top_right] - integral_img_arr[bottom_left] + integral_img_arr[top_left]

I tried inputting a normal 0 indexed array index and printing out the results but the padding and the flipping of the coordinates is just really confusing and I can't seem to wrap my brain around it all. The input to sum_region is (0,0) and (2,1) which to me in the original image corresponds to the 1 and the 8 and the output I get is 3 when it should be 27. I don't understand where the original author means the origin would be for x,y in the original image, and thus I'm not 100% on what is supposed to be inputted.
This is what I was using to test it.
import numpy as np
from integral_image import *

original_image = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
],)


integral = to_integral_image(original_image)
print(original_image)
print(integral)

# region in the original image

top_left = (0,0)
bottom_right = (2,1)
sum = sum_region(integral, top_left, bottom_right) 
print(f"Original Top left: {original_image[top_left]}")
print(f"Original Bottom Right {original_image[bottom_right]}")

print(f"Sum: {sum}")




What do you mean by "it doesn't work". Do you get an error message? Do you get a wrong result? You need to be very explicit and clear, because we do not know what you know, and cannot see what you see on your screen. Also, we don't have your to_integral_image(), so we cannot run your code.

The swapping of the coordinates is simply because the function takes (x, y), where x is the horizontal coordinate and y the vertical one. But NumPy arrays are indexed with (row, column), so vertical comes first.

all your tuples must have a comment (or blatantly obvious naming convention) specifying the index order (xy/ji or yx/ij, or say "top left" or "left top"). the code you're trying to reuse is terrible because it doesn't do that AND because it uses indexing into fixed length tuples. it should use something like left, top = left_top; right, bottom = right_bottom and then integral_img_arr[bottom, right] - integral_img_arr[top, right] ... -- code isn't just making it work, it's making it obvious

@CrisLuengo Hey man sorry about that it's my first question, I've added to_integral_image() to the code. The input to sum_region is (0,0) and (2,1) which to me in the original image corresponds to the 1 and the 8 and the output I get is 3 when it should be 27.  I don't understand where the original author means the origin would be for x,y in the original image, and thus I'm not 100% on what is supposed to be inputted. Hope thats clearer.
